APNS Silent notification if app is not installed
Below is my sample silent notification payload. If I send the notification i got the 200 status code. But if i uninstall the app and try to send silent notification again then also i got the same status code of 200. Is there any way to find out if app is uninstall on my device on sending silent notification?
$silent_notification_message_array = [
    'aps' => [
        'content-available' => 1
    ],
    "call_status" => "disconnected"
];


If you are asking if the silent notification can detect if a device has uninstalled your app then the answer is no.
APNs stores all device tokens and handles them itself.
All that 200 code is telling you is that the device token is still in their system(Whether or not the device is still active).
